# Invalid credentials when passing with Javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, post

I am trying to send a POST request using jquery but it keeps saying incorrect credentials.

### What I tried

I tried most of the methods in the first google search. I feel I am doing something else wrong here. e.g.

```
var auth = btoa('username:password');


var username = "username";
var password = "pass";

var auth = btoa('username:password');

console.log(auth);

var settings = {
  "url": "https://sct.intutrack.com/api/prod/trips/start",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + auth
  },
  "data": {
    "tel": "9560688565",
    "src": "22.572646, 88.36389500000001",
    "dest": "28.6139391, 77.2090212",
    "srcname": "Intugine Technologies",
    "destname": "Bangalore",
    "client": "XYZ",
    "vendor": "Rivigo",
    "vehicle": "MH01x123",
    "invoice": "123ZXYZ",
    "eta_hrs": "75"
  }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

### The error I am getting

```
{"errorCode":403,"msg":"Invalid credentials","requestData":{"x-forwarded-for":"103.240.236.196","x-real-ip":"103.240.236.196","x-real-port":"22691","host":"sct.intutrack.com","connection":"close","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8"}}
```

Comment: `btoa('username:password');` will encode the string `username:password`. Is that supposed to be the contents of the variables `username` and `password`?

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be base64 encoded?

Comment: @Sreeram I am not sure. VLAZ I have replaced the actual username and password and hid it over here.

Comment: It might just be what the error says - incorrect credentials, or a wrong encryption mechanism.

Comment: @Sreeram I can assure you, they are correct because first I did the same thing with python and got correct results. Now, for some reason I have to use JS and can't figure out what I wrong.

Comment: Do you have test credentials you can share?

Comment: Can you create a room?

Comment: Are you getting any other errors in the Console of the browser's Developer Tools? For instance, something about a preflight OPTIONS request getting a 403 response?